# Выделить конкретное слово в google

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Собственно, вопрос таков, есть код парсера из другого вопроса, выглядит он так:

```
 function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name : "Поиск",functionName : "selectText"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Скрипты", entries);
};


function selectText(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()


  var arrData = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues() 

  for(var row = 0; row < arrData.length; row++){
    for(var col = 0; col < arrData[0].length; col++){
      if(arrData[row][col].toString().match('будет') == 'будет'){
        sheet.getRange(row+1, col+1).setFontWeight("bold")

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Можно ли, как-то выделить конкретно слово "будет", а не всю ячейку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент такой технической возможности не существует.

Google Apps Script является серверной технологией, предоставляющей интерфейс взаимодействия с API Google (в самом общем смысле этой фразы). Никакое из вариантов API не позволяет управлять пользовательским интерфейсом приложений. Исключением, пожалуй, являются функции детектирования активного положения курсора в [Таблицах](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()) и [Документах](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getCursor()), но и они сильно ограничены. Скорее всего, они были созданы в пользу увеличения гибкости Google Apps Script. Никаких других упоминаний о взаимодействии с ячейкой, а тем более с работой курсора в режиме редактированя ячейки Таблицы в документации нет.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/236451)

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko Почему не является?

Comment: @0xdb Мне кажется, что это больше похоже на комментарий, а не на полноценный ответ, хотя я могу ошибаться

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko Если действительно так. как утверждает автор, то это самый лучший ответ. Если это не так, то всё равно ответ, только ошибочный. Автору бы не помешало аргументировать ответ хотя бы цитатой из офф. дока.

Comment: @0xdb Полностью с Вами согласен

Comment: Примите как авторитетное мнение. Я бы с удовольствием привел дополнительные комментарии, но документация не распространяется на тему управления пользовательским интерфейсом. Т.е. функция отсутствует как таковая. Я исправлю ответ как только будут новые сведения.